# How do i work in Swift 5 with protocol function parameters that use protocols with associated types (i.e. .pickerStyle())

Tags: swift, protocols, associated-types

I am using SwiftUI and would like to set the pickerStyle of a View depending on the number of items in the Picker. With a few items, SegmentedPickerStyle() is ideal, with more WheelPickerStyle() is better.

```
}.pickerStyle(productsObserver.product.productFamilies?.count ?? 0 < 5 ? SegmentedPickerStyle() : WheelPickerStyle())
```

The function signature reads:
`func pickerStyle<S>(_ style: S) -> some View where S : PickerStyle` which i have learned uses a generic in the functiona signature because PickerStyle uses an associated type.

It shouldn't be so difficult a problem and probably isn't - Protocols should work like this easy = , but i can't see it.
Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: `pickerStyle` is a generic method that accepts a concrete type (at compile-time) that conforms `PickerStyle`. So, it cannot be either `SegmentedPickerStyle` or `WheelPickerStyle` - it has to be one or the other. Whichever it is, will make the compiler create a concrete method, e.g. `pickerStyle<SegmentedPickerStyle>`.

Comment: Thanks for the ELI5, i think i get it now. Can you also help me with a solution? Thought about impementing my own class (i.e. DynamicPickerStyle), but i guess that just shifts the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pickerStyle` is a generic method that accepts a concrete type (at compile-time) that conforms `PickerStyle`. So, it cannot be either `SegmentedPickerStyle` or `WheelPickerStyle` (determined at run-time) - it has to be one or the other.

So, one suggestion would be to create a view modifier and apply the picker style conditionally. The critical difference here is that it returns a conditional view of type `_ConditionalContent<TrueContent, FalseContent>`.

```
struct PickerStyleOption<P1: PickerStyle, P2: PickerStyle>: ViewModifier {
    let predicate: () -> Bool
    let style1: P1
    let style2: P2
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        if predicate() {
            content
                .pickerStyle(style1)
        } else {
            content
                .pickerStyle(style2)
        }
    }
}
```

For convenience, you could create an extension:

```
extension View {
    func pickerStyleOption<P1: PickerStyle, P2: PickerStyle>(
            _ condition: @autoclosure @escaping () -> Bool,
            then style1: P1, 
            else style2: P2) -> some View {

        self.modifier(
            PickerStyleOption(predicate: condition, style1: style1, style2: style2)
        )
    }
}
```

And use it like so:

```
Picker(...) {
   ...
}
.pickerStyleOption((productsObserver.product.productFamilies?.count ?? 0) < 5, 
   then: SegmentedPickerStyle(), else: WheelPickerStyle())
```

Comment: Thanks!Makes sense. That sounds like a plan. I will try it during the weekend and will let you know next week if i have further questions.

Comment: Been taking more than a weeked to get back to this project .Thanks so much for this elegant workaround and also the insightful explanation!